# I can't run web.py from command line

Tags: python, virtualenv, web.py

I just setup a new virtualenv project and installed web.py, created a test application to see if things are running as expected but it's not starting and not throwing any errors

Im using Python 2.7.13 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3

webservice.py

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)


class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'Kitty'
        return 'Hello '+ name


if __name__ == "main":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

requirements.txt

```
appdirs==1.4.0
nose==1.3.7
packaging==16.8
Paste==2.0.3
pyparsing==2.1.10
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
six==1.10.0
web.py==0.38
```

from the command line python webservice.py does nothing

Comment: urls = () is there

Comment: may be you paste here cmd you running?

Comment: "(venv) kn$ python webservice.py" as described but nothing happens, no error messages no nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid if statement in `webservice.py`. Please replace it by:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Comment: it's a silly mistake but as you see - quite hard to debug :)